# Use gulp to copy the contents of one glob file into a line of another glob file

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace, gulp-tap

I'm working on a web component build process that takes the contents of a HTML file and puts them into a string in my javascript file.

I want to get the contents of `/src/foo/bar.html` and add them to `/dist/foo/bar.js`

At the moment, I'm using `gulp-tap` and `fs` to read in the html which works, and I'm using `gulp-string-replace` to add the string to my js file, as follows:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs = require('fs');
const replace = require('gulp-string-replace');
const tap = require('gulp-tap');

gulp.task('add-html', function () {
    // Use these variables for Gulp-string-replace
    const startHTML = "<!-- Start html -->";
    const endHTML = "<!-- End html -->";
    const regEx = new RegExp(
        startHTML + "[\\s\\S]*" + endHTML,
        "i"
    );
    let htmlInjection;
    return gulp.src(['dist/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
            // get to html file
            const htmlFile =
                file.path
                    .replace(/\.js$/i, ".html")
                    .replace(/dist/, "src");

            // read html, clean it up and add it to htmlInjection
            fs.readFile(htmlFile, function (err, data) {
                if (!err && data) {
                    const cleanHTMLString =
                        data.toString()
                            .split('\n')
                            .join('')
                            .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
                            .trim();
                    htmlInjection =
                        startHTML +
                        cleanHTMLString +
                        endHTML;
                }
            });
        }))
        .pipe(replace(regEx, htmlInjection)) // Replace <!-- Start html --> foo <!-- End html --> with <!-- Start html --> <bar></bar> <!-- End html -->
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This isn't working yet, as `htmlInjection` is undefined when `replace` happens. I believe this is due to the pipes being async.

I was referencing this Question [Passing a variable between pipes in Gulp 3.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506157/passing-a-variable-between-pipes-in-gulp-3-9-1/48655965) and was wondering if this approach is even the best approach possible?

Are there any easier ways to achieve what I'm trying to here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that lowers complexity relatively well.

By using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) instead of [gulp-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace), you can get the file path inside your replace function like so:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
 
gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('filename', function() {
      // Replaces instances of "filename" with "file.txt"
      // this.file is also available for regex replace
      // See https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#instance-properties for details on available properties
      return this.file.relative;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

So instead of having two pipes, one for `gulp-tap` and one for `gulp-string-replace`, I just have the one `gulp-replace` pipe. My code now looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs = require('fs');
const replace = require("gulp-replace");

gulp.task('compileHTML', function () {
    const startHTML = "<!-- Start html -->";
    const endHTML = "<!-- End html -->";
    //Creates the regEx this ways so I can pass the variables.
    const regEx = new RegExp(startHTML + "[\\s\\S]*" + endHTML,"i");
    return gulp.src('dist/**/*.js')
        .pipe(replace(regEx, function () {
            let htmlFile = this.file.path.replace(/\.js$/i, ".html").replace(/dist/, "src");

            const html = fs.readFileSync(htmlFile);
            const cleanHTMLString =
                // cleaning logic
            injectHTMLContent = startHTML + cleanHTMLString + endHTML;
            return injectHTMLContent;
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

It's not the cleanest implementation, but hopefully this will help others in the future.